# MySQL / PHP: cannot perform two separate queries on same database?

Tags: mysql

I have one database with two tables: "music" and "agenda".

But for some reason once I have queried one table, I cannot perform a similar query on the other table. Or in any case, its variables are empty.

I'd think I could just keep the connection open and perform a second query after the first "while". Like so:

```
<?php

    mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
    mysql_select_db('erikverwey');      

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agenda ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 2") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $count++;
            $date[$count] = $row['date'];
            $time[$count] = $row['time'];
            $place[$count] = $row['place'];
            $venue[$count] = $row['venue'];
            $who[$count] = $row['who'];
            $concert[$count] = $row['concert'];
            $urlvenue[$count] = $row['urlvenue'];
        }

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM music ORDER BY id LIMIT 0, 5") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            $count++;
            $song[$count] = $row['song'];
            $artist[$count] = $row['artist'];
            $duration[$count] = $row['duration'];
            $url[$count] = $row['url'];
        }

    mysql_close();

?>
```

But no. In this case, all the variables from the table "music" remain empty.

I've been looking for an answer, but no luck. I'm still new to MySQL, though, so apologies beforehand if this is standard stuff. Thanks!

Comment: Erm, is your second query after the `mysql_close()`?

Comment: Don't use original MySQL extension - it is deprecated.

Comment: I noticed that you're using the mysql_* family of functions. As of [PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), those functions are deprecated, and set to be removed in future versions of PHP. It is advisable to switch to either mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: @Wrikken: yes, it's after the mysql_close

Comment: Also what Wrikken said is probably accurate; you shouldn't close the connection before you're done using it, which is what `mysql_close` does. However, I'm glad that you're thinking of resource management!

Comment: didn't know about mysql_* being deprecated. will look into that, thanks.

Comment: but it also doesn't work if I keep it open, i.e. only close it after the second query

Comment: After the second `mysql_query()`, can you put `echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";`, just to see if there's an error coming out? Also, you might want to use `echo "Rows: " .  mysql_num_rows($calendar);` just to make sure rows are even being returned!

Comment: I don't know, but somehow the problem solved itself. Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Actually, no the problem hasn't solved itself. Grrr. See update in question.

Comment: The answer to the error message is 0:

Answer (score 0):

I found the glitch. Because the counter "$count" was used a second time, it started where it left off and couldn't find any data.

Use a different counter, also in the variables (!), and all is good.